# Fit two piece wise functions to data in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the red line when I plot it. I need to fit two piecewise functions to approximate and get values of k, a, and b. If x <=15, fit the green line (right side of 0) and if x > 15, fit the right blue curve.

[image]

Comment: Why not fitting the full graph with a non-linear fit?

Comment: I am trying to implement this paper: http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Eleojia/projects/upsampling/upsampling_sa08.pdf and I need two piecewise differentiable functions.

Comment: right ...nevertheless the function to fit seems to be log( exp( -|x| ) + exp( -x^2 ) `...at least from `-100` to `+100`